# Dojo aspect inheritance

Tags: inheritance, dojo

I'm having trouble with dojo aspect and how it behaves with inheritance.

I have class called child1 and another class called child2.
Both classes inherit from parent.

Child1:

```
return declare("child1", [parent], ...
```

Child2:

```
return declare("child2", [parent], ...
```

The implementation of Child1 and Child2 are very different.
Parent has a method that child1 needs to aspect to:

```
this.own(aspect.before(this, "_onChange", lang.hitch(this, "_onRowSelected"), true));
```

Everything works fine with child2 until child1 is called.
At that point whenever the `_onChange` method is called from Parent, the function `child1._onRowSelected` is run.... regardless of where the call originated from.

I would think that the aspect would only involve the object that created the aspect call in child1, and wouldn't affect child2 whatsoever.

The only thing that I can think of, is that it looks like the instantiation of child1 and child2 is done within the HTML template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use inheritance, why do you use `aspect` ?
It is not necessary in such case.

In `Child1`, simply create a method `_onChange` like this:

```
_onChange: function() {
    this._onRowSelected();
    this.inherited(arguments);
}
```

It will achieve the same with no need of `aspect`